# If $\big[[\hat{A},\,\hat{B}],\, \hat{A}\big] = 0$ does that mean $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ commute?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, linear-algebra

Let's say we have the following identity:
$$\Big[\big[\hat{A},\,\hat{B}\big],\, \hat{A}\Big] = 0.$$
Expand the LHS:
\begin{align}
\Big[\big[\hat{A},\,\hat{B}\big],\, \hat{A}\Big] &= 2\hat{A}\hat{B}\hat{A} - \hat{A}\hat{A}\hat{B} - \hat{B}\hat{A}\hat{A} \\ &= 2\hat{A}\hat{B}\hat{A} - \hat{A}^2\hat{B} - \hat{B}\hat{A}^2
\end{align}
Obviously the above is $0$ if $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ commute; however, are there any other circumstances which the above equation is zero? Do I have enough information to conclude that $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ commute?

Comment: It is not enough to conclude that $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ commute. If, for example, $[\hat A, \hat B]$ is a scalar $\neq 0$, then identity is satisfied as well. This is the case for the usual quantum mechanics commutator $[\hat x, \hat p] = i \hbar \Rightarrow [[\hat x, \hat p], \hat x] = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Cream points out in a comment, no, you do not have enough information to draw that conclusion. What you are asking for is if:

$$[[\hat{A},\hat{B}], \hat{A}] = 0 \quad \quad \stackrel{\color{red}{?}}{\implies} \quad \quad [\hat{A}, \hat{B}] = 0.$$

But what you have "shown" instead is that:

$$[\hat{A},\hat{B}] = 0 \quad \quad \implies \quad \quad [[\hat{A},\hat{B}], \hat{A}] = 0.$$

But this is pretty trivial, since the commutator of anything with zero is zero!

If you continue your calculation a little further, you should be able to show that:

$$[[\hat{A},\hat{B}], \hat{A}] = 0 \quad \quad \implies \quad \quad [\hat{A}^2, \hat{B}] = 2 \hat{A} \,[\hat{A}, \hat{B}].$$

So yes, $[\hat{A},\hat{B}] = 0$ satisfies this condition, but it isn't the only condition that does. A nice example from introductory Quantum Mechanics is given by @Cream in the same comment: $$[[\hat{x},\hat{p}],\hat{x}] = 0, \quad \quad \text{but} \quad \quad [\hat{x},\hat{p}]\neq 0!$$

However, the above condition is satisfied, since $$[\hat{x}^2, \hat{p}] = 2 \,\hat{x} \,[\hat{x},\hat{p}].$$